# ASP.Net MVC 5 patrón repositorio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Cordial saludo

Necesito un poco de  ayuda acerca de como crear un patron repositorio. con ASP.Net MVC y entity Framework.

Gracias

Comment: ¿El `DbContext` de entity framework es basicamente un repositorio, que es lo que estás buscando hacer?

Comment: Hola Marcela, bienvenida a [es.so]. Para poder ayudarte se requiere un previo trabajo de investigación, las fuentes que has consultado y/o ejemplos de código. Teniendo esto tu pregunta tendrá mayor atención y será más sencillo que resuelvas tus dudas. Mientras tanto te recomiendo [esta fuente](http://www.eltavo.net/2014/08/patrones-implementando-patron.html) para que saques dudas puntuales :D

Comment: checa esto https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/